# Add list-style-type to react inline style

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to add a style to a list in React:

```
const listStyle = {
  list-style-type: none,   // Error
};
```

and then:

```
const Box = () => (
   <ul style={listStyle}>
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
   </ul> 
);
```

But I get an unexpected token error. Is `list-style-type` not supported?

Even doing it inline gives an error:

```
<ul >
  <li style={{list-style-type: "none"}}>One</li>
  <li style={{color: "red"}}><Checkbox />Two</li>     
</ul>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your problem is with name of the style properties, it should be in the camel case format:

```
<li style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>One</li>
```

Documentation on inline styling in react is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing list-Style-Type as the camel case format...guess I should have left out the hyphens

Comment: Thanks, I tried many ways but it didn't work.